# How can I attach a MvxCommand to a BottomBar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using [this](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar) library to add a `BottomNavigationBar` to my project. I am also using MvvmCross for my framework for this project. I cannot figure out how to bind a `MvxCommand` to my `BottomBar` though. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Here is roughly what my `MvxCommand` in the `ViewModel` looks like:

```
public ICommand OnTabSelectedCommand 
{
    get { return New MvxCommand(() => OnTabSelected()); }
}
```

My `BottomBar` creation looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var recycler = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.menuList);
        var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;


        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarFinder);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        _bottomBar = BottomBar.AttachShy((CoordinatorLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ListCoordinator),
                         FindViewById(Resource.Id.menuList), savedInstanceState);

        _bottomBar.SetItems(new[]
              { new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_recents, "Recents"),
                new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_favorites, "Favorites"),
                new BottomBarTab(Resource.Drawable.ic_nearby, "Nearby") }
            );

        _bottomBar.SetOnMenuTabClickListener(this);

        _bottomBar.SetActiveTabColor(Color.Red);

        _bottomBar.MapColorForTab(0, "#7B1FA2");
        _bottomBar.MapColorForTab(1, "#FF5252");
        _bottomBar.MapColorForTab(2, "#FF9800");
    }

    public void OnMenuTabSelected(int menuItemId)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public void OnMenuTabReSelected(int menuItemId)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

Comment: Add a "if (menuItemId == xxx) myViewModel.OnTabSelectedCommand.Execute()" in the "OnMenuTabSelected" method of your view.

Comment: @hugo It's not wanting to work. I am calling `ListHomeViewModel.OnTabSelectedCommand.Execute();`, but that results in an error. Do I need to make the command `static`?

Comment: No, if you use you declaration like this "public class myview : MvxActivity<MyViewModel>", you will have a property named "ViewModel" which is of type "MyViewModel".  And then you need to call "ViewModel.OnTabSelectedCommand.Execute()". Sorry for the wrong viewmodel usage...

Comment: @hugo It works now! Thank you. If you want to write an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your Activity like this:

```
public class MyView : MvxActivity<MyViewModel>
```

You will be able to access the property "ViewModel" which is of type "MyViewModel".

Then you just need to call your command with:

```
ViewModel.OnTabSelectedCommand.Execute();
```

This call should be included with a switch command in your:

```
public void OnMenuTabSelected(int menuItemId)
{
    // Do something
}
```